# Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body in react-admin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I am using `react-admin`framework, and I have written my own `DataProvider`. I am trying to accomplish that when an User is created, an instance of UserPossession is created as well. My code bellow accomplishes that, but `react-admin` `Front-end` just displays the warning message:

```
Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body
```

I checked the Network tab in Developer Tools and every request to server is correct, there is no error. Which leaves me confused and stuck with this, because I have no idea what that warning means or why is it even occuring.

My code is a part of `convertDataRequestToHTTP` constant and looks like this:

```
if (resource === 'User') {
  url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}`;
  options.body = params.data;
  httpClient(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(options.body),
  })
  .then(response => (
    url = `${apiUrl}/Location`,
    options.method = 'POST',
    options.body = JSON.stringify({
       "odata.type": "HardwareDatabase.UserPossession",
       "Name": response.json.Login,
       "UserId": response.json.Id
    }),
    httpClient(url, {
      method: options.method,
      body: options.body
    })
  ));
}
```

If you have any questions regarding the code I can clarify.

Thank you for any ideas in advance.

Comment: `if (resource === 'User') { resource = 'User';` If resource is `USER` then set resource to `USER`?

Comment: Also is this valid js syntax? `.then(response => ( resource = 'Location',`. This code is saying on completion of the promise then return an object, but `resource = 'Location',` is not a valid object constructor. Perhaps you meant to use `{` instead of `(`, but then shouldn't be ending lines in commas...

Comment: @tic I will edit the code so it does not contain that worthless line, the syntax is correct.

Comment: You can not send a body in a GET request, if you want to request some data you can pass it via the url as request params, otherwise you might want to change the API to a POST request instead

Comment: @KhaledOsman But I am using the `POST` method as far as I am aware right?

Comment: @AdamSulc the error message hints that its not set correctly somehow, you might want to add some console.logs or debugger statement and see the response being sent, or take a look at the network tab in chrome devtools and see if its actually a post method

Comment: @KhaledOsman I am using extension called Debugger for Chrome, and I set up some breakpoints where I checked the values which seems correct to me. Also the Network tab only returns right calls to Back-end. It is really weird. Thank you for the ideas though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are stating that this code snippet is a part of `convertDataRequestToHTTP` I might see the issue. `httpClient` cannot be used in this constant since it creates duplicit calls to API or in your case, this Warning. Correct way would be to only state the `options` constant.

```
url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}`;
options.body = JSON.stringifiy(params.data);
options.method = 'POST';
```

Later in the constant that converts response from OData to mandatory React Admin format, state the `httpClient`.

```
 params.data = {
    "odata.type": "HardwareDatabase.UserPossession",
    "Name": response.json.Login,
    "UserId": response.json.Id
 };
 httpClient(`${apiUrl}/Location`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the GET method for `XMLHttpRequest` and `fetch` don't support request bodies.

A temporary work around I found was to use the [`axios` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), which does let you send GET with request bodies.

```js
const res = await axios.get("/api/devices", { 
  data: { deviceName: 'name' } 
})
```